# Unable to deploy my nextjs application which can get data from expressjs backend by running api

Tags: express, next.js

I am deploying it in cpanel but somehow getting error afteruploading static build is working fine but other one is not my server.js code is

```
// server.js
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const hostname = "localhost";
const port = process.env.port || 3000;
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
     createServer(async (req, res) => {
          try {
               // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
               // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
               const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
               const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;

               if (pathname === "/a") {
                    await app.render(req, res, "/a", query);
               } else if (pathname === "/b") {
                    await app.render(req, res, "/b", query);
               } else {
                    await handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
               }
          } catch (err) {
               console.error("Error occurred handling", req.url, err);
               res.statusCode = 500;
               res.end("internal server error");
          }
     })
          .once("error", (err) => {
               console.error(err);
               process.exit(1);
          })
          .listen(port, () => {
               console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`);
          });
});
```

Please suggest what are the things i need to change in this file or others i am having a domain called risposta.in  and when i had a chat with provider they said i have a problem in my .js files but how can i check these many files.

i have tried uploading empty nextjs project with dynamic build but it also doesnot work please help.

[image: This is the error i get after uploading website and switching on node server]